# What markup / doctype to use on a mobile site

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile, smartphone

I'm doing my first mobile site, which will be separate to the main site and thus only targeted at mobile devices (mostly Android and iPhone but ideally also feature phone compatible too). The site design/function will be relatively simple with a search form and results (http://m.monster.co.uk/ is an example but even simpler).

I'm trying to decide what markup language to use and searching here and the wider web seems to throw up lots of conflicting answers, mainly I guess due this being an evolving area.

This same questions was asked here in [Jan '11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794423/which-markup-language-to-use-for-the-new-web-site-desktop-mobile) -  prior to that I was going to use XHTML 1.0, but a linked article discourages that  - now I'm thinking of HTML4.01 strict - perhaps declaring as HTML 5 (with a text/html header thus not XML mode) with an eye to the future, but I'll only be using basic 4.01 tags.

I've looked at 5 sites which are competitors to my client and 2 appear to use HTML5 with text/html header, 2 use XHTML 1.0 also with text/html header and 1 (which I believe to be the oldest) uses WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.1 (is that same as XHTML Mobile Profile?) - can I assume anything with "wap" in it is dead?

It seems technology wise, I can *almost* assume I'm developing for a desktop - would this be correct in Jan '13? (still need answer since December please) Apart of course from design and layout and navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. So you are saying HTML5? With a text/html header?

Comment: HTML5, most devices you will be targeting on mobile will support the basics of HTML5.  Look here for framework inspirations: http://html5boilerplate.com/, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/.  You will want to leverage Media Queries and fluid layouts to achieve a responsive layout.

Comment: You may want to check out DARL as well: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/